Find total length of time in multiple values of a dataset that overlaps with a given period of time
I have a dataframe like the following:
df <- tibble(
  period = list(
    c("09:34:00-20:40:00", "20:57:00-21:00:00"),
    c("16:03:00-19:00:00", "19:10:00-21:00:00", "21:15-24:00"),
    "7:02:00-13:20:00",
    c("9:00:00-12:15:00", "14:30:00-16:30:00")

  )
)

I want to create a new variable that contains the number of total hours (including decimal points) between the period 12:00 to 15:00, in any of the concatenated periods (or the single time, not concatenated. The output should look like the following:
df <- tibble(
  period = list(
    c("09:34:00-20:40:00", "20:57:00-21:00:00"),
    c("16:03:00-19:00:00", "19:10:00-21:00:00", "21:15-24:00"),
    "7:02:00-13:20:00",
    c("9:00:00-12:15:00", "14:30:00-16:30:00")

  ),
  hrs = list(3.0,0,1.33,0.75)
)

How can I create this new variable extracting the number of hours that overlap with the specified period?

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(anytime)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest(period) %>% 
  separate(period, into = c("p1", "p2"), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(p1, p2), 
                ~anytime(paste("2020-01-01", .x), 
                         tz = "UTC", asUTC = TRUE))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(p1, p2), 
                ~case_when(.x > as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 15:00", tz = "UTC") ~ 
                             as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 15:00", tz = "UTC"),
                           .x < as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 12:00", tz = "UTC") ~ 
                             as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 12:00", tz = "UTC"),
                           .default = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(hrs = difftime(p2, p1, units = "hours")) %>% 
  summarize(period = list(period), 
            hrs = sum(hrs), 
            .by = id) %>% 
  select(-id)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   period    hrs           
#>   <list>    <drtn>        
#> 1 <chr [2]> 3.000000 hours
#> 2 <chr [3]> 0.000000 hours
#> 3 <chr [1]> 1.333333 hours
#> 4 <chr [2]> 0.750000 hours

Created on 2024-12-13 with reprex v2.0.2
If you want to do this for multiple periods and calculate the total sum of overlapping hours, then we can do it like below (I am borrowing Thomas's idea by using pmin and pmax to make this look cleaner):
total_hours <- \(p1, p2, s){ 
  xt1 <- pmax(pmin(p1, s[2]), s[1])
  xt2 <- pmax(pmin(p2, s[2]), s[1])
  return(abs(difftime(xt2, xt1, units = "hours")))
}

s1 <- c(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 12:00", tz = "UTC"), 
        as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 15:00", tz = "UTC"))
s2 <- c(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 04:00", tz = "UTC"), 
        as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 06:00", tz = "UTC"))
s3 <- c(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 17:00", tz = "UTC"), 
        as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 18:00", tz = "UTC"))

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest(period) %>% 
  separate(period, into = c("p1", "p2"), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(p1, p2), 
                ~anytime(paste("2020-01-01", .x), 
                         tz = "UTC", asUTC = TRUE))) %>% 
  mutate(hrs = Reduce("+", lapply(list(s1, s2, s3), 
                                  \(s) total_hours(p1, p2, s)))) %>% 
  summarize(period = list(period), 
            hrs = sum(hrs), 
            .by = id) %>% 
  select(-id)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   period    hrs           
#>   <list>    <drtn>        
#> 1 <chr [2]> 4.000000 hours
#> 2 <chr [3]> 1.000000 hours
#> 3 <chr [1]> 3.333333 hours
#> 4 <chr [2]> 2.750000 hours

Created on 2024-12-16 with reprex v2.0.2

Thanks so much! This makes sense and is very clean. As a follow up, is there any way to make this more generalizable? For example, I'm wondering about setting to time ranges, for instance what if I want to add all values from the range 12:00-15:00 AND from 4:00-6:00? Can this be integrated?

@flâneur see the updates. You just need to make sure that your time ranges are ordered correctly, i.e. start is not more than the end, and that they are not overlapping. For instance, you cannot have 12-15 and 14-16.

Thanks, this works great! I really appreciate it!

You can use pmin + pmax to bound the time intervals with the given time window, and then calculate the total duration, e.g.,
wnd <- strptime(c("12:00:00", "15:00:00"), "%H:%M:%S")

df %>%
  mutate(
    tot_hrs =
      sapply(
        period,
        \(s) sum(sapply(
          strsplit(s, "-"),
          \(x) {
            diff(pmin(pmax(strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S"), wnd[1]), wnd[2]),
              units = "hours"
            )
          }
        ), na.rm = TRUE)
      )
  )

which gives
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  period    tot_hrs
  <list>      <dbl>
1 <chr [2]>    3
2 <chr [3]>    0
3 <chr [1]>    1.33
4 <chr [2]>    0.75


Regarding the weird output from @M--'s feedback, not sure if any version of package makes that difference
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Sweden.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Sweden.utf8
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Sweden.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_Sweden.utf8

time zone: Europe/Stockholm
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.12           microbenchmark_1.4.10 igraph_2.0.3
 [4] data.table_1.15.4     lubridate_1.9.3       forcats_1.0.0
 [7] stringr_1.5.1         dplyr_1.1.4           purrr_1.0.2
[10] readr_2.1.5           tidyr_1.3.1           tibble_3.2.1
[13] ggplot2_3.5.1         tidyverse_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.5     jsonlite_1.8.8   compiler_4.4.2   tidyselect_1.2.1
 [5] scales_1.3.0     R6_2.5.1         generics_0.1.3   munsell_0.5.1
 [9] pillar_1.9.0     tzdb_0.4.0       rlang_1.1.3      utf8_1.2.4
[13] stringi_1.8.4    timechange_0.3.0 cli_3.6.2        withr_3.0.0
[17] magrittr_2.0.3   grid_4.4.2       hms_1.1.3        lifecycle_1.0.4
[21] vctrs_0.6.5      glue_1.7.0       fansi_1.0.6      colorspace_2.1-0
[25] tools_4.4.2      pkgconfig_2.0.3


I am getting 45 for the last row (not sure why it gets converted to minutes).

@M-- that sounds weird... what about using diff.difftime explicitly?

Same: https://i.sstatic.net/v87xSRwo.png

@M-- I attached my session info, I don't know if it is caused by some package version issues
